# How do I get my menulet to look like this

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsstatusitem

How do i get this effect with a menulet application. I just want the window effect nothing else.

### [image: Heading]

My current app looks like this. please if someone could shed some light it would be appreciated. Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to do custom drawing to achieve this effect, which is not standard in NSWindow. Take a look at this example code: (MAAttatchedWindow) http://mattgemmell.com/source.

Answer (score 0):

This cocoa control exactly what many people here are looking for: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/axstatusitempopup.

I have successfully implemented this without any issues and might provide step-by-step details later. would love to answer any specific questions if necessary.